# Склонение слова "полчаса"

Tags: склонение

Фраза такая: "Большую часть из отведенного ему получаса..." Но что-то меня взяло сомнение: правильно ли тут употреблено склонение слова "полчаса"?
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У существительного *полчаса* весьма оригинальная парадигма склонения. Посмотрим справочный материал :

> Толковый словарь русского языка (Ожегов С., Шведова Н)
> ПОЛЧАСА
> {Р.п.} получаса и (разг.) полчаса, в других косвенных падежах только с полу..., м. род (согласуется так же, как полвека).
> {полвека - в им. и вин. п. согласуется с прилагательным в форме мн. ч., со сказуемым-глаголом или кратким страдательным причастием - в форме мн. ч. или ср. р. (при наличии определения глагол-сказуемое или страда-тельное причастие - всегда в форме мн. ч.)}.
> Половина часа, тридцать минут. Нет свободного получаса. Эти полчаса - решающие. Прошло полчаса. Прошли (пройдут) полчаса. Отсчитано полчаса. Отсчитали последние полчаса. || уменьш. полчасика, {Р.п.} получасика, м.род || прил. получасовой, -ая, -ое. Получасовой перерыв.
>
> Викисловарь :
>  Морфологические и синтаксические свойства
>
> Существительное, неодушевлённое, мужской род; согласуется с прилагательными в форме мн. ч. (прекрасные полчаса́); со сказуемым-глаголом или кратким страд. прич. в форме мн. ч. или ср. р. (забылись полчаса́; забылось полчаса́). В ед. ч.: род. п. — получа́са; дат. п. — получа́су, твор. п. — получа́сом, предл. п. — получа́се.

Получается, что форма косвенных падежей производится от начальной формы **получас** (др.-рус. *получасие*), но на практике это слово (в И. и В.п.)  превратилось в *полчаса*.

Answer (score 3):

Напрасно сомневаетесь: [Толковый словарь Ожегова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/171994), [Энциклопедический словарь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/130808/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0), [Малый академический словарь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/49320/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%CC%81) (который оказывается особенно полезен, т. к. содержит информацию об ударении в слове "получаса") и еще с дюжину других словарей подтверждают нормативность формы "получаса" как формы Р. п. ед. ч. слова "полчаса".

Answer (score 1):

Не сомневайтесь.
Получаса.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно сомневаетесь.
Нет, с точки зрения употребления форм Вам правильно ответили.

Но если копать глубже, то формы получаса, получасу и т.д. строго говоря *не являются* косвенными падежами от полчаса, а порождены словом "получас". И это легко доказать. Достаточно добавить определение:
И. *первые* полчаса, 
Р. *первого* получаса, 
Д. *первому* получасу...

Убедительно? ;)))

Аналогичная штука происходит со словом "полтора", но там, увы, сложнее найти подобный аргумент.

Вообще подобные слова с "внутренним склонением" в русском языке испытывают сильную тенденцию к упрощению... Как и порожденные от числительных и счетных форм ("пол" - как раз такое "хитрое числительное"). Но это отдельный разговор, не возьмусь здесь и сейчас излагать...,

Comment: Очень убедительно! Спасибо!
Но на ЕГЭ вариант один.

Конечно, на этом сайте можно рассуждать о тонкостях языка. Но, пардон, не могу изжить в себе училку. Русский язык - наука точная.
Поэтому на конкретный вопрос следует давать чёткий, однозначный ответ.

А то вконец запутаем сомневающегося. ;))